# teaching tag: remove?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [teaching](/questions/tagged/teaching) tag looks to be a 270 or so questions, all, uniformly, off topic or nonconstructive. Shall we apply the usual mechanism?

Comment: With the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

[teaching](/questions/tagged/teaching) should be burninated, as it seems to just give information about the context in which the question is asked, not about the question itself.

Before burninating the tag, any questions that need to be closed should be closed; it would be very difficult to find the questions that need closing after the tag has ceased to exist.